# How can I implement a string filter algorithm in iOS that mirrors the contact auto complete in 'Messages'?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, autocomplete

In iOS, when you start to type someone's name in to send a new SMS/iMessage etc, an auto complete list pops up.

I am trying to recreate the way this search algorithm works, however it's not as straight forward as you might think. You can try this out on your device to see what I mean, but for example if I type "Joh" or "Brow" then "John Brown" will show up. However typing "ohn" will not show any results. To make it even more difficult, typing in "Mr Green" will allow "Mr Evan Green" to show... try it yourself in messages, it's probably easier to understand that way.

Is there an easy way to implement this autocomplete algorithm? (I have an array of NSStrings containing names, and a substring to filter them with).

If there's no easy way, how would you go about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should create a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) out of your strings for this purpose. You can also use [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) (a improvement over the TRIE) or [suffix array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) (stripped down data structure based on the suffix tree). Check out [this](http://rmandvikar.blogspot.in/2008/10/trie-examples.html) link for algorithm using Trie.

Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487576/trie-vs-suffix-tree-vs-suffix-array) for difference between these data structures.

Idea of suffix tree is to have path to every suffix of the input string and than you can use tree search to find if a random string is matching the input string very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the first name from the last name. Then, check if either string starts with the typed in substring. That will give you the desired behaviour for the first described case.

The second case is more difficult and it is harder to both implement and describe. A way to do it would be to explode the typed in characters by a space, so that you have an array of substrings ("Mr" and "Green"). Then, perform the same check as before; check each in the array to see if it matches the start of the first name or last name. If it does, add it to the results.

Comment: This is what I started doing, but then it gets tricky, because typing "Mr White" shouldn't list "Mr Green" as a result. Fixable with a bit more code though - I'll continue this way for now, it's just a rather large, ugly and potentially inefficient function - I was hoping there was an easier or cleaner way :)

Comment: Is "Mr" a special field in the Contacts app? Also, when it comes to linguistic processing, quite often you get bulky functions — the processing is simply quite complicated.