# Suffix Array and Suffix Tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, suffix-tree, suffix-array

what are the shortcomings of `suffix tree` over `suffix array` and vice versa ?

Why we need two different thing is there any instance where suffix array fails but suffix tree succeeded and vice versa

Comment: particular case of  [  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487576/trie-vs-suffix-tree-vs-suffix-array ] marked as duplicate

Comment: I am not an expert, so I won't post this as an answer, but in my limited experience suffix arrays are simple to build whereas suffix trees are less so. OTOH, suffix trees encode certain information directly, e.g. the common prefix of a sub-set of strings, which would require further processing to get from a suffix array.